# Коммуникация процессов в Java

Tags: java, процесс, связь

Как на Java я могу из одного процесса отправить сообщение другому. В С++ я знаю, что можно использовать: file mapping, pipes, mailslots, sockets. К примеру идея использования какого-нибудь текстового файла и запись в него, чтобы другой процесс прочитал из него мне не очень понравилась. Есть какое-то простое решение, как в С++? В Java я новичок, хочу сделать подобие системы телефонной связи. Телефон 1 передает сообщение АТС, которая передает это Телефону 2.

Comment: для ясности - `file mapping, pipes, mailslots, sockets` - это все не является частью какого либо языка. Кроме того, процесс программы, написанной на C++ не отличается от процесса программы, написанной на Java (с точки зрения операционной системы). В таком случае вы можете выбрать тот способ взаимодействия, который считаете подходяшим, и можно уже искать конкретные способы как это имплеметировать в Java/

Comment: В этом коренное отличие Java от других языков. В Java вы можете наладить общение между объектами, с точки зрения процессов, то тут не важно кто тогда будет проводить коммуникацию.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вопрос решил этот **class** [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]